# Only input text is working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a script that gets the total number of inputs and get the percentage thats left to complete. But my script only gets `type="text"`. Any ideas on how I can fix this? Here's my code

```
var bad = 0;
var cback=function(){
    bad=0;
    $('.form :text').each(function (i,e) {
        if ($.trim($(e).val()) == "") bad++;
    });
    $('.congrats').css("display", "block").text(bad + ' missing(Completed '+count()+')');
     //else $('.congrats').hide();

     $(".top").css("width", 100-(bad / $('.form :text').length)*100 + "%");
}
$(document).delegate('.form :text','focus',cback);
$(document).delegate('.form :text','keyup',cback)

function count(){
    return 100-(bad / $('.form :text').length)*100 + "%"
};
```

So how can I have `type="password"` and so fourth? Do I do the same code for all of them? Whats your approach guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd do that like this

```
var inputs = $('.form :input').not('button, [type="button"], [type="submit"]').on({input: cback});

function cback() {
    var bad = inputs.filter(function() {
        return !this.value.length;
    }).length,
        total = inputs.length;

    $('.congrats').show().text(bad + ' missing(Completed ' + ((100 - (bad / total) * 100).toFixed(2) + "%") + ')');
    $(".top").css("width", 100 - (bad / total) * 100 + "%");
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/W78sW/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

[Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('.form [type="password"]') //selector for type="password" inside element with form class
```

---

```
$('.form :text, .form [type="password"]')//select type="text" and type="password"
```

Comment: What would a complete example look like? Because I also have `css("display", "block").text` and I'm not sure how it would work

Comment: @user302975 just replace `$('.form :text')` with `$('.form :text, .form [type="password"]')` .

Comment: Its still not working... Look at the bottom part of my code, I also have `:text` mentioned many times

Comment: @user302975 Make a fiddle .

Comment: As you can see the password doesn't count. How can I make it count?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all inputs with following selector

```
$('.form input')
```

Comment: But how can I exclude the submit button?

Comment: `<button>` isn't an `<input>`, it shouldn't match this selector.

Comment: `<input type="submit">. Its only looking for `<input type="text>` and I want to be able to exclude `<input type="submit">`

Comment: @user302975 Sorry, but why you can't use `<button type="submit">...</button>` instead of `<input type="submit">`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.form input').not(':input[type=submit]');
```

see fiddle for result:
http://jsfiddle.net/NtL6f/